# Is it possible to wake up intel cores with INIT-SIPI-SIPI sequence with all cores in real mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, multicore, fasm

I'm using DOS to boot up and start my application **test.exe**. This program starts the BSP (Bootstrap Processor) in real mode and accesses the APIC table at `FEE0:0000` to enable the SVI (Spurious vector interrupt) at offset `0x0F0`and send an `INIT-SIPI-SIPI` sequence using both `ICR_low` (offset 0x300) and `ICR_high`(offset 0x310). The BSP enters inside a loop **jmp $** to stop executing and lets the APs (Application Processor) execute code at address `0000:8000`and print a character.

It seems the messages aren't being sent to the APs because I don't see any of them print anything to the display..

I'm using FreeDos in real mode. To compile I'm using **FASM** (flat assembler)

I used **OsDev** manual that includes the code I'm using to test (with some modifications) as simple as possible, to see if I could get it working. I also referred to the **Intel programmers** manual and other specs as well as tutorial at Code Project.

I'm only trying to wake the APs up and execute some simple code. All examples that I found enter into unreal mode, protected mode, long mode or are focused in multicore processing. I'm only writing this code to understand how it works.

My code is:

```
    format MZ  

    USE16 

    start:
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    xor sp, sp
    cld
    ;Clear screen                
       mov ax, 03h
       int 10h
    ;Move payload to the desired address
       mov si, payload
       mov cx, payload_end-payload + 1
       mov bx,es
       mov ax,7c0h
       mov es,ax
       mov di,400h                 ;07c0:400 = 8000h
       rep movsb
       mov es,bx
    ;Enable APIC table
       call enable_lapic
    ; Wakeup the other APs
      ;INIT
       call lapic_send_init
       mov cx, WAIT_10_ms
       call us_wait
      ;SIPI
       call lapic_send_sipi
       mov cx, WAIT_200_us
       call us_wait
      ;SIPI
       call lapic_send_sipi

      ;Jump to the payload
      ;Para teste de acordar nucleos
      jmp 0000h:8000h ;voltar esse depois


    ;Payload é o código que será movido para o endereço físico 0x08000
    payload:
      mov ax, cs
      mov ds, ax
      xor sp, sp
      cld
    ;Only print letter 'A' directly to video memory
      mov cx,0b800h
      mov es,cx
      mov di,00h
      mov al,41h
      stosb
      cli    
      hlt    
    payload_end:

    enable_lapic:
      mov ecx, IA32_APIC_BASE_MSR
      rdmsr
      or ah, 08h ;Enable global APIC flag
      wrmsr
      and ah, 0f0h ; Mask to obtain APIC_Base address
      mov DWORD [APIC_BASE], eax ;Save it
      shr eax,16
      mov bx,fs
      mov fs,ax
      mov ecx, DWORD [fs:APIC_REG_SIV] ;Load value from SIV (FEE0:00F0) to ecx
      or ch, 01h    ;bit8: APIC SOFTWARE enable/disable
      mov DWORD [fs:APIC_REG_SIV], ecx ;Save it
      mov fs,bx
      ret

    IA32_APIC_BASE_MSR = 1bh
    APIC_REG_SIV       = 0f0h
    APIC_REG_ICR_LOW   = 300h
    APIC_REG_ICR_HIGH  = 310h
    APIC_REG_ID        = 20h

    APIC_BASE         dd 00h

    ;CX = Wait (in ms) Max 65536 us (=0 on input)
    us_wait:
      mov dx, 80h               ;POST Diagnose port, 1us per IO
      xor si, si
      rep outsb
      ret
      WAIT_10_ms     = 10000
      WAIT_200_us    = 200

    lapic_send_init:
      mov eax, DWORD [APIC_BASE]
      xor ebx, ebx
      shr eax,16
      mov cx,fs
      mov fs,ax
      mov DWORD [fs:APIC_REG_ICR_HIGH], ebx
      mov ebx, 0c4500h
      mov DWORD [fs:APIC_REG_ICR_LOW], ebx  ;Writing the low DWORD sent the IPI
      mov fs,cx
      ret

    lapic_send_sipi:
      mov eax, DWORD [APIC_BASE]
      xor ebx, ebx
      shr eax,16
      mov cx,fs
      mov fs,ax
      mov DWORD [fs:APIC_REG_ICR_HIGH], ebx
      mov ebx, 0c4608h
      mov DWORD [fs:APIC_REG_ICR_LOW], ebx  ;Writing the low DWORD sent the IPI
      mov fs,cx
      ret
```

I expect the BSP enters into an infinite loop and the APs execute code at 0000:8000 and print 'A' at video memory.

11/06/2019
Hello everybody!

Now I have a code that can access protected mode. Because I'm with difficult to move to unreal mode I decided to stay in protected mode and enable all cores by this way.

It is a simple code but how Michael Petch said, I tried to do it in a bootloader situation.

Here is the code:

"format binary as 'bin'

```
use16

org 0x7C00

boot:
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    xor sp, sp

   ;Clear screen
   ; mov ax, 03h
   ; int 10h

   ;Set VGA text mode 3
    mov ax,0x3
    int 0x10

   ;Move payload to the desired address
    mov si, payload
    mov cx, payload_end-payload + 1
    ;mov si,boot2
    ;mov cx,boot2_end-boot2+1
    mov bx,es
    mov ax,7c0h
    mov es,ax
    mov di,400h                 ;07c0:400 = 8000h
    rep movsb
    mov es,bx

    ;jmp 0000h:8000h

    call enableA20Line

    call enterProtectedMode

use32

    ;Enable the APIC
     call enable_lapic

    ;INIT
     call lapic_send_init
     ;mov cx, WAIT_10_ms
     ;call us_wait
     .Verify1:
        PAUSE
        MOV EBX,[APIC_BASE]
        MOV EAX,[EBX+0x300];
        SHR EAX,12
        TEST EAX,1
        JNZ .Verify1
     MOV EDI,[APIC_BASE]
     ADD EDI,0xB0
     MOV dword [EDI],0

    ;SIPI
     call lapic_send_sipi
     ;mov cx, WAIT_200_us
     ;call us_wait
     .Verify2:
        PAUSE
        MOV EBX,[APIC_BASE]
        MOV EAX,[EBX+0x300];
        SHR EAX,12
        TEST EAX,1
        JNZ .Verify2
     MOV EDI,[APIC_BASE]
     ADD EDI,0xB0
     MOV dword [EDI],0

    ;SIPI
     call lapic_send_sipi
     ;mov cx, WAIT_200_us
     ;call us_wait
     .Verify3:
        PAUSE
        MOV EBX,[APIC_BASE]
        MOV EAX,[EBX+0x300];
        SHR EAX,12
        TEST EAX,1
        JNZ .Verify3
     MOV EDI,[APIC_BASE]
     ADD EDI,0xB0
     MOV dword [EDI],0

    ;mov eax,0x8000
    ;jmp DWORD[eax]
    ;jmp boot2
    ;jmp 0x8000
    ;jmp $
    ;cli
    ;hlt
    mov eax,0x000b8010
    mov dword[eax],0e41h
    cli
    hlt

use16

enableA20Line:
    mov ax,0x2401
    int 0x15 ;enable A20 bit
    ret

enterProtectedMode:
    lgdt[gdt_pointer]
    mov eax,cr0
    or eax,0x1 ;set the protected mode bit on special cpu reg CR0
    mov cr0,eax

    jmp CODE_SEG:exit ;long jump to the code segment
    exit:
    ret

gdt_pointer:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start
    dd gdt_start
CODE_SEG = gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG = gdt_data - gdt_start

gdt_start:
    dq 0x0        ;NULL segment
gdt_code:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_end:

;CX = Wait (in ms) Max 65536 us (=0 on input)
 us_wait:
  mov dx, 80h               ;POST Diagnose port, 1us per IO
  xor si, si
  rep outsb
  ret

  WAIT_10_ms     = 10000
  WAIT_200_us    = 200

use32

enable_lapic:
  mov ecx, IA32_APIC_BASE_MSR
  rdmsr
  or ah, 08h        ;bit11: APIC GLOBAL Enable/Disable
  wrmsr

  and ah, 0f0h
  mov DWORD [APIC_BASE], eax

  mov ecx, DWORD [eax+APIC_REG_SIV]
  ;or ch, 01h                                ;bit8: APIC SOFTWARE enable/disable
  or edx,01FFh
  mov DWORD [eax+APIC_REG_SIV], ecx

  mov DWORD[eax+0B0h],00h
  ret

lapic_send_init:
  mov eax, DWORD [APIC_BASE]

  xor ebx, ebx
  mov DWORD [eax+APIC_REG_ICR_HIGH], ebx

  mov ebx, 0c4500h
  mov DWORD [eax+APIC_REG_ICR_LOW], ebx  ;Writing the low DWORD sent the IPI
  ret

lapic_send_sipi:
  mov eax, DWORD [APIC_BASE]

  xor ebx, ebx
  mov DWORD [eax+APIC_REG_ICR_HIGH], ebx

  mov ebx, 0c4608h
  mov DWORD [eax+APIC_REG_ICR_LOW], ebx  ;Writing the low DWORD sent the IPI
  ret

 IA32_APIC_BASE_MSR = 1bh

 APIC_REG_SIV       = 0f0h

 APIC_REG_ICR_LOW   = 300h
 APIC_REG_ICR_HIGH  = 310h

 APIC_REG_ID        = 20h

 APIC_BASE        dd  00h



boot2:
    mov ax,DATA_SEG
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov fs,ax
    mov gs,ax
    mov ss,ax

    mov esi,hello2
    mov ebx,0b8000h
    .loop:
        lodsb
        or al,al
        jz halt
        or eax,0x0100
        mov word[ebx],ax
        add ebx,2
        jmp .loop
halt:
    cli
    hlt
    hello2: db "Hello world!",0
boot2_end:

use16

payload:
    mov ax,cs
    mov ds,ax
    xor sp,sp

    mov ax,0b800h
    mov es,ax
    mov di,20h
    mov ax,0e45h
    mov [es:di],al

    cli
    hlt
    ;jmp $

payload_end:

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 ; pad remaining 510 bytes with zeroes
dw 0xaa55 ; magic bootloader magic - marks this 512 byte sector bootable!"
```

Now I'm searching for a delay routine to send init and sipi messages. I think this is the problem because this is not working yet.

The BSP prints letter "A" at position 10, and anyone should print another letter at position 20, but only "A" is printed.

Any ideas to help me while I'm searching how to put it to work?

Thanks in advance.

OBS: now I learned how to use the "qemu" emulator and I'm simulating all inside it.

SECOND EDIT: THE CODE WORKS. I'm using qemu emulator with only 1 core. When I use with 2 or more cores, code works!!

You need to use "qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu 486 -smp 2 'path'" without quotes.

12/06/2019
I've tried to run it in a real computer but it only do a reset loop.
Have anyone a clue about it?

14/06/2019
Hello! I'm here again!
I deal with this big problem about linear addressing inside DOS and I solve it with a previous .exe program that copies kernel.bin (program that send INIT-SIPI-SIPI) to a 0xXXXXXXXX address. Inside kernel.bin I put "org 0xXXXXXXXX", now I do not need to solve all pointers I use. Now INIT-SIPI-SIPI sequence is working.

Link: [Switch from protected mode to real mode in a DOS EXE program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772558/switch-from-protected-mode-to-real-mode-in-a-dos-exe-program)

Another thing that I need to do is exit protected mode before exit program. If I do not do that, DOS crash. So I used the link above to solve linear addressing (by copying most part of the code to a known memory position) and return control to DOS.

It was funny because I put AP cores in a loop printing "Hello from another core" on the screen and the BSP exit program and goes back to dos. No matter what you do, the message can not be cleaned.

Know I will work on a simple trampoline code to put cores in different positions and executing 4 counter routines. It is the beginning of a function to wake up cores and give them some work. After I will implement MP and MDAT table detection to do by the right way.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to do here. Although there are multiple issues here the primary one that stands out is how you are treating the APIC_BASE. The APIC_BASE is actually a 32-bit Linear address (often at 0xFEE000F0) below the 4GiB barrier at the top of memory. You are treating this address as a real mode segment:offset pair that can only address memory in the first ~1MiB of memory. FEE0:00F0 and 0xFEE000F0 are not the same. FEE0:00F0 is the physical(linear) address (0xFEE0<<4)+0x00F0=0xFEEF0. Obviously 0xFEE000F0 and 0xFEEF0 aren't the same physical address in memory

Comment: It seems like you have done this in an attempt to avoid entering into unreal mode. Unfortunately to address the memory where the APIC_BASE is well above the 1MiB region you need to do something like enter unreal mode to allow a segment (in this case FS) to address the entire 4GiB rather than the normal 64KiB limit. This allows real mode programs to address the entire 4GiB of the memory address space including where the APIC_BASE is

Comment: Getting into unreal mode by setting up a GDT is normally straight forward except for under DOS. In DOS you don't know what segment the program is loaded in so the GDT base in the GDTR has to be computed at run time (and can't be computed at assemble and link time). This other answer of mine does such a calculation before using the `LGDT` instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772558/switch-from-protected-mode-to-real-mode-in-a-dos-exe-program

Comment: Since the APIC_BASE can in theory be anywhere in memory the A20 gate should be enabled.

Comment: I'd say if you are trying to experiment I would not do it while running under DOS. I'd start with getting your code working in a bootloader situation. An example of such code (which is rather similar to yours in some ways) can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48764646/3857942

Comment: I missed that the APIC base address is an absolute address because how I read the APIC_BASE_MSR and it returns FEE00000 in real mode, I assumed that it is a segment:offset address. Now I know why it is not working. I need to go to protected or unreal mode to do that. I was running it on FASM to do a simple test. Now I think it will be more simple because I will use this code in OpenWatcom 32 bit protected mode for DOS. Maybe I do not need to care about GDT or segment and can access all 4GB memory. I will try it and, if it works, I return with code. Now I'm working on a precision timer.

Comment: On a real computer are you booting as USB media? If so is it USB Floppy (FDD) emulation or Hard Drive emulation (HDD) which is settable in the BIOS? Ir did you install it as an ISO image? If floppy disk emulation you may need to have a [BIOS Parameter block in your bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277702/custom-bootloader-booted-via-usb-drive-produces-incorrect-output-on-some-compute) to avoid code being overwritten by drive geometry data.

Comment: I tried with usb media but I'm confused about how use it. So I change output file to .exe and remove both 2 eof lines to execute it in FreeDOS. I think the protected mode and jmp far after "mov cr0,eax" is the problem because if I remove it, code execute on real mode and print a letter.
I saw another post by you where you use a protected code to load a kernel and print "MDF"(I do not remember) at video memory. I'm using it as a reference to see what is wrong.

Comment: Did you ever resolve the problem and did any of the answers help?

Comment: In the 2nd listing under enable_lapic, it appears 1ffh is being 'or'ed into edx and then edx is not used for anything.  It looks like this was a typo and should have been 'or'ed into ecx.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to wake up intel cores with INIT-SIPI-SIPI sequence with all cores in real mode?

Yes (maybe). There's 2 options:

a) If the CPU/s support x2APIC, then you can enable it and send the INIT-SIPI-SIPI sequence using MSRs (without needing to access memory mapped registers at an address that you can't access in real mode).

b) For xAPIC; it might be possible to change the address that the local APIC uses (by writing to the APIC_BASE MSR) so that it can be accessed in real mode. However, this requires extreme care because the local APIC shouldn't be placed anywhere that is already in use, and all of the space you can access in real mode is likely to already be in use. To get around that you'll probably need "chipset specific" code to modify where accesses are routed (to RAM, to PCI bus, ..) followed by code to reconfigure MTRRs to suit. The APIC_BASE MSR is also a little "CPU specific" (won't exist on 80486, might not exist on CPUs from other vendors). Note: I wouldn't consider this option sane or practical (especially for code that needs to work on more than one computer).

Note: You should only start CPUs that the firmware says exist (and should not broadcast the INIT-SIPI-SIPI sequence to faulty and disabled CPUs); and it's very likely that you won't be able to access ACPI tables (needed to find out which CPUs exist) in real mode. For this reason (because it doesn't make sense to start other CPUs without using protected mode for something) my answer should be considered "for academic purposes only".

Comment: Just a side note: if using QEMU/KVM for testing - you can write the APIC base, you can read the modified APIC base but the APIC base doesn't actually get remapped in memory. Of course the end result won't be what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

When I first encountered this question I knew part of the problem is how DOS adds a level of complexity to code that requires work with linear addresses. I suggested doing it as a bootloader to test where the complexities of a DOS environment are removed. A legacy BIOS bootloader will always have the code placed at physical address 0x07c00. In real-mode physical and linear addresses are the same thing. As long as your bootloader sets the segments to 0x0000 when it starts and an `org 0x7c00` directive is used - all memory references will be relative to the beginning of memory. A [segment:offset pair](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.htmlv) of 0x0000:0x7c00 = physical address (0x0000<<4)+0x07c00.

Knowing exactly where your program is in physical memory is important because the `LGDT` instruction is one of the few instructions that loads information that requires a **linear address**:

> Loads the values in the source operand into the global descriptor table register (GDTR) or the interrupt descriptor table register (IDTR). The source operand specifies a 6-byte memory location that contains the **base address** (a **linear address**) and the limit (size of table in bytes) of the global descriptor table (GDT)

Your code defines the GDT record as:

```
gdt_pointer:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start
    dd gdt_start
```

In a bootloader that uses `org 0x7c00` `dd gdt_start` will be filled in with the offset of `gdt_start`. That will be an address of 0x7cxx where `xx` is some distance from the beginning of the bootloader origin point where `gdt_start` resides. It works out well that the value of `gdt_start` is also the same as the linear address!

---

### How does this differ when using DOS?

It is assumed in the information below that you have modified the program so it no longer has an `org 0x7c00`, no longer has padded 512 bytes (and the boot signature) and that the top line of the file is now `format MZ` for DOS executable.

The problem with DOS is that programs get generated with offsets relative to the beginning of the segment(s) that DOS loads the code and data to. These segments may differ each time a program is run depending what is in memory. At assembly time we don't know where in memory our code is loaded, so we can't possibly know the physical(linear) addresses until the program is loaded by DOS and running. This is unlike a bootloader that is always loaded at the same physical address.

Why does this all matter? When FASM generates code for your `MZ` (DOS) EXE program the offsets generated will be relative to the beginning of the segment DOS will be loading us to. If the `gdt_start` is at offset 0x60 (as an example) from the beginning of the segment, the GDT pointer `dd gdt_start` will be filled in with the value `0x60`. Since it will be treated as a linear address by the `LGDT` instruction that is telling  LGDT that the GDT itself is at linear (physical address) 0x00000060. That is an address in the middle of the interrupt table, not in our program! The first time a segment is reloaded after going into protected mode the processor will look for the GDT at the wrong memory location, read bogus descriptor tables and most likely crash (triple fault/reboot). Effectively the moment you do `jmp CODE_SEG:exit` which loads *CS* selector that is an index into a bogus GDT it will crash.

If DOS loaded your program starting at the beginning of segment 0x1230 (as an example) and the GDT was at offset 0x60 in the program then the linear address (physical) of the GDT in memory is actually (0x1234<<4)+0x60=0x123a0. What you need to do when your program starts running is determine what segment DOS loaded the program to and do this computation and update the GDT address in the `gdt_pointer` structure. Using FASM to create DOS programs without `segment` directives places all code and data in the same segment. You can get the segment by retrieving the value of *CS* and then you shift that value left by 4 bits and then add that to the offset stored in the `gdt_pointer` by the assembler. You could do this at the beginning of the code when you load *CS* into the other registers. It has to be done after you setup *DS*:

```
mov eax, cs
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

mov ebx, eax
shl ebx, 4
add [gdt_pointer+2], ebx

; mov ss, ax
; xor sp, sp
```

I have removed setting up SS:SP as DOS already set them up for us when our program was loaded by the DOS EXE loader. I move *CS* to *EAX* so that the upper 16-bits of *EAX* will be zero which simplifies the code for the calculation. We copy *EAX* to *EBX*, shift the value left by 4 bits (same as multiplying by 16 decimal) and adding that directly to the GDT offset portion of `gdt_pointer` (`gdt_pointer`+2 is the position where the GDT offset is stored). The assembler would have stored the offset of `gdt_start` at `gdt_pointer+2` and we are adjusting it to be a linear address.

If you were to assemble the code and run it - it will crash!

---

### I Setup the GDT with a Linear Address - Now What?

The GDT is not the only address in your code that needs to be fixed up like the GDT. Consider the jump into protected mode:

```
jmp CODE_SEG:exit ;long jump to the code segment
exit:
```

The label `exit` is relative to the beginning of the segment we are loaded in. The `CODE_SEG` selector points at a 4GiB flat code descriptor with base 0x00000000. `Exit` will have a small offset, let us say for sake of argument it is 0xf5. The FAR JMP would  go to `CODE_SEG:0xf5` which would be memory address 0x000000f5 which is not where we are loaded. There are a number of ways to solve this but most involve FAR JMPing to a fixed up address that we have to compute at run-time. One mechanism is to use a non-zero base in the GDT code descriptor, but that option is outside the scope of this answer. The easiest to understand is creating a 6 byte pointer (32-bit offset and 16-bit segment) in memory and doing an *indirect* FAR JMP instead. We can fix up the offset of `exit` the same way we did `gdt_start`. At this point I'd rename `exit` to `pmode` or something that makes sense.

To do the fix up we can do it at the start like the `gdt_pointer` fix up. The starting code would now look something like:

```
mov eax, cs
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

mov ebx, eax
shl ebx, 4
add [gdt_pointer+2], ebx
add [pmode_farptr], ebx

; mov ss, ax
; xor sp, sp
```

In the same area of the bootloader you have the `gdt_pointer` structure you'd add a new `pmode_farptr` structure that looks like this:

```
gdt_pointer:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start
    dd gdt_start
CODE_SEG = gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG = gdt_data - gdt_start

pmode_farptr:
    dd pmode      ; Offset of pmode label
    dw CODE_SEG   ; Segment to use
```

The indirect FAR JMP can now be done this way:

```
    jmp fword [pmode_farptr];long jump to the code segment
                            ;indirectly through 6 byte (fword)
                            ;pointer at pmode_farptr
pmode:
    ret
```

---

### I've now Fixed up my FAR JMP but it still crashes!

The problem is what happens after the FAR JMP which is now:

```
    jmp fword [pmode_farptr];long jump to the code segment
                            ;indirectly through 6 byte (fword)
                            ;pointer at pmode_farptr
pmode:
    ret
```

At the `pmode` label you are now in 32-bit protected mode. There is `ret` but you haven't set up *SS* to point to a valid data descriptor, you haven't set up *ESP* the stack pointer, and you haven't setup the other segment registers! Even if you set up the stack after `pmode` to point to the same place as the real-mode stack was pointing, the return address on the stack will be a problem. A 2 byte NEAR return address was pushed on the stack when `call enterProtectedMode` was done. We are now in 32-bit protected mode where NEAR addresses are 4 bytes. The easiest thing to do is ditch the `ret` and move the `pmode` label to the code you already have for 32-bit mode. This code:

```
    call enterProtectedMode

use32

    ;Enable the APIC
     call enable_lapic
```

Can now become:

```
    call enterProtectedMode

use32
pmode:
    movzx esp, sp           ; Extend SP to ESP zero extending upper bits
    mov eax, ss
    shl eax, 4
    add esp, eax            ; ESP is now the linear address of original SS:SP pointer
    mov ax, DATA_SEG        ; Reload segment register with 32-bit flat
                            ; flat data selector
    mov ss, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    ...
```

**Note**: Remove the `pmode` label and the `ret` after the `jmp fword [pmode_farptr]` as they are no longer needed.

---

### Far from a Great Situation

After making the changes above you should be able to work on your APIC code. There are many shortcomings in this code. See Brendan's answer about APIC specific issues, but beyond that there are several issues that should be addressed:

- Your code blindly copies the AP (application processor) payload to 0x8000. What happens if the DOS stack was in that area? Although highly unlikely, if the stack did collide with the code the program would likely crash.
- The code in the payload was copied to 0x8000. Although this works for simple payload code, if you add data inside the payload all the generated offsets to the data will be wrong. Your payload was originally part of the entire program and wasn't at offset 0x0000 from the beginning of the segment.
- In the payload you copy *CS* to *DS* but *CS* hasn't been set. The copying of *CS* to *DS* won't do what you expect, but it doesn't hurt the basic payload you wrote which doesn't rely on *DS* being a particular value - so it doesn't matter.
- The AP code has no way to communicate data with the Bootstrap Processor (BSP) because the APs don't know where in memory DOS loaded the original program. This will also severely restrict what your payload code can do. With a bootloader you know you could always access the bootloader and BSP data because you knew that data was in memory relative to 0x0000:0x7c00.
- These observations effectively summarize as: the payload code probably won't be able to do anything sophisticated, and attempts to do so will give you unexpected behaviour. You can modify the code to deal with all these deficiencies, but that is outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: Michael, thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I was in trouble with linear addressing inside DOS but a code written by you in another post helps me a lot!
I solve linear addressing by using a program to load kernel.bin in a known address and inside it I used org directive.
I'm still working on it and will return with my results.

Comment: @vitoralho : Althought his may not have answered your question (you may not know until you get things goin) you can consider upvoting this answer. If later on you find that this answer really was a solution to the problems you should consider Accetping it as an answer. More on all this (and how it works) can be found in this information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768